# HtmlElement from a WebBrowser object strips double quotes from HTML

Tags: html, vb.net

I am grabbing an HTMLElement from a browser object and then using getElementById to grab the element I want.  When the element is grabbed into the HtmlElement object double quotes around attributes like `<input type="checkbox" name="test1" />` becomes `<input type=checkbox name=test1>`.

It is removing the double quotes and backslash from the HTML available in the HtmlElement.  Is there anyway to get the HTML element from Visual Basic .NET code and keep the true HTML formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to function as design.